# Как лучше разместить выбранные элементы?

Tags: html, css, javascript

В общем, у меня есть страница редактирования курса, как мне лучше организовать такую возможность:

Выбираем из списка преподавателя для данного курса, а потом 2-го и 3-го и т.д. можно было бы добавить. Как лучше это организовать, чтобы красиво и удобно было, может, есть такой элемент?

Мой вариант:

```
Преподаватели:
Носков А.А <кнопка убрать>
Пушкин А.А <кнопка убрать>
Кряков А.А <кнопка убрать>
<кнопка добавить>
```

Или можно лучше организовать?
Ну, сверху идет редактирования описания курса и т.д., и снизу такая возможность добавить преподавателя или убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заполнять можно с клавиатуры или мышью. Притом либо так, либо так. Когда заполнение идет и мышью, и клавиатурой одновременно, заполнение усложняется.

С клавиатуры, например, так: [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) с навигацией по списку вниз-вверх. А на пустой ввод переходить к следующему вводу.

Мышью, например, так: вывести список всех (15-20 со скроллингом), на клик добавлять.

Можно и даже лучше учесть оба способа - список с автокомплитом. Удалять с клавиатуры сложнее... мышью - крестиком.

Answer (score 0):

```
             к13.1  з13.1 ...
Носков А.А     □      ■
Пушкин А.А     ■      □
Кряков А.А     ■      ■
```

Используй чекбоксы

Comment: Допустим, будет 40 преподавателей, и будет список с 40 чекбоксов? И для 30 предметов очень трудно заполнять будет.